# How to align lines in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

Is there a good way to make horizontal lines actually line up in Crystal Reports?  I can select text and field objects, right-click, and do various sizing and alignments.  But that's not an option with a line.  I need header fields underlined (and for whatever reason, our standard says to NOT use underline), and I want them to line up across the report.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a pain, but I've found one way to do it.

Both field and line items have a right-click menu option called "Size and Position".  It doesn't take just any value, especially with Snap to Grid turned on (and doesn't always take exactly what you choose with it not turned on), but you can carefully make sure each line has the same Y value (for horizonal lines).  And, if you want them to align and be the same length as the field headers they are underlining, compare each header field X and Width values, and make each line also match that.

Answer (score 0):

In design mode, you can add horizontal guide lines by clicking in the ruler (the vertical one) fields will get sticky to it.

You can also select several fields, right click "Align > Bottoms" and them move the fields to the guide lines.

You can also format a single field to "lock its position and size", then Align the others to it

Comment: Yeah, but I couldn't get lines to stick to the guide lines, nor would the align work with lines.  I can make the fields line up using "align" but not the lines under them.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to select all the lines you want to left align, move them to the far left with the left cursor key until they hit the left margin and keep pressing the left key until they all align themselves. Just a trick!

Answer (score 0):

Put a bottom border on the header Text Object.